# Hyperbolic PDE that is Non-Homogenous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Say I have a PDE of form $$Au_{xx} + Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} = xy$$
and that A,B, and C are constants chosen so that the PDE is hyperbolic. How do I go about solving this system? I solved the homogeneous case first, but I am not sure if this is the first step and if so how to extend it to solve the actual PDE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a particular solution of the complete equation. Since $x\,y$ is a polynomial of degree $2$, it seems reasonable to look for a solution that is a polynimial of degree $4$. We see that
$$
(x^2\,y^2)_{xy}=4\,x\,y.
$$
This suggets a solution of the form
$$
u=a\,x^4+b\,x^2\,y^2+c\,y^4.
$$